# My own exception handler still throwing the exception and crashing the application

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, handler

Winforms app.
This is the main:

```
  static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Add handler for UI thread exceptions
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(UIThreadException);

        // Force all WinForms errors to go through handler
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        // This handler is for catching non-UI thread exceptions
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
            Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
            MessageBox.Show("Unhadled domain exception:\n\n" + ex.Message);

            Application.Exit();


        // It should terminate our main thread so Application.Exit() is unnecessary here
    }

    private static void UIThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Unhandled exception catched.\n Application is going to close now.");


        // Here we can decide if we want to end our application or do something else
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

this is where i purposely generate an exception

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int zero = 0;
            //int number = 1 / zero;

            throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

stackTrace:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Unable to find the specified file.
  Source=NewPostSharpSolution
  StackTrace:
       at NewPostSharpSolution.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\Joao\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NewPostSharpSolution\NewPostSharpSolution\Form1.cs:line 21
       at NewPostSharpSolution.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Joao\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NewPostSharpSolution\NewPostSharpSolution\Program.cs:line 30
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The handler shows a messagebox of the exception but still breaks the application...

Is there something i am missing? I thought implementing this handler would let me decide what to do with the exception??

Comment: Why are you try-catching `MessageBox.Show` ???

Comment: It's time to clean up your try/catches.  I know why they are all there, but if you don't do it now then troubleshooting this is going to just get harder.   Would you mind removing all of them and then posting the stack trace?

Comment: Edited the main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application.

That means - you cannot handle the exception. You can log information about exception, show some message etc. But you cannot prevent the application from terminating.

Comment: So this is not the same as a try catch? Would you have a solution for that?

Comment: @JoaoVitor nope. It is used mainly for logging purpose. If application crashed (i.e. unhandled exception has occured), this is a last chance to save some information which will help you define cause of exception later. Application will be in undeterminate state anyway, even if there would be an option to prevent it from terminating. So there is no sence of keeping alive something that crashed.

Comment: Could i make it just exit normally and not giving that message in windows "appname.exe has crashed" or something like that?

Comment: @JoaoVitor but your application has crashed. With no excuses. If you want to prevent that message, you should handle exceptions as early as possible. If you are getting file, then either check if it exists, or wrap that code in `try .. catch` to prevent application from crashing

Comment: No, the application crashes because the OP throws the exception in the constructor of the form, which is instantiated in the `Main` method.

Comment: @taffer seems like you think that I have pointed at some other reason of application crash. Can you please tell what is that reason?

Comment: It is nothing wrong with the MSDN article, it just seems to be a little bit misleading here. The OP created a somewhat wrong example, which crashes of course. But it could be avoided by try-catching `Application.Run(new Form1());` line. Further exceptions, which are thrown while the message pump works can be handled (here `Application.Run` is not even called before the crash). And the last sentence of the OP clearly tells that this was his intention.

Comment: @taffer I didn't get you. Why are you telling about msdn article? Why OP example is wrong? It clearly shows what is *unhandled exception*.

Comment: @Sergey *"Is there something i am missing? I thought implementing this handler would let me decide what to do with the exception??"* - this sentence and the fact that he tries to handle `Application.ThreadException`, which is never called in his case is a hint. The handler in fact **does** allow not to shut the application down, but his example crashes before reaching that point.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is the best practice to terminate the application whenever an unhandled exception is caught (after generating an error report or something), handling this event will definitely **not** shut down the application.

In your case the application is terminated because you throw an exception in the constructor of the `Form1`, which is instantiated in your `Main` method. *So eventually you will have an unhandled exception in your `Main` method.*

Throw the exception for example in the `Load` event of your form and your app will not be closed (unless you leave the `Application.Exit` lines there...)

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // throw new Exception("Crash");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("No crash");
    }
}
```